# Select top rows from each group

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, row

I have to retrieve the top rows from each group, based on the max values of two columns.

This is the table:

```
tag_series_id   |   tag_season_num  |   tag_episode_num
269653              2                   24
269653              3                   1
269653              3                   2
269653              3                   3   
281593              1                   9
281593              1                   11
281593              1                   10
```

The result set should be the record with the maximum `tag_season_num` and `tag_episode_num`.   `tag_season_num` should be higher priority.

The result set should be this:

```
tag_series_id   |   tag_season_num  |   tag_episode_num
269653              3                   3   
281593              1                   11
```

These are some of my failed attempts:

```
SELECT tag_series_id, tag_season_num, tag_episode_num, tag_watch_status
FROM taggedshows WHERE 
GROUP BY tag_series_id, tag_season_num
ORDER BY tag_season_num desc, tag_episode_num desc;

SELECT tag_series_id, tag_season_num, tag_episode_num 
FROM (SELECT * from taggedshows
ORDER BY tag_series_id, tag_season_num desc, tag_episode_num desc) x
GROUP BY tag_series_id;

SELECT tag_series_id, MAX(tag_season_num), MAX(tag_episode_num)
FROM taggedshows
GROUP BY tag_series_id;
```

Comment: You may try this approach:         SELECT distinct ts.tag_series_id,

(select MAX(tag_season_num)  from taggedshows where tag_serie_id= ts.tag_serie_id) as tag_season_num,
(select MAX(tag_episode_num)  from taggedshows where tag_serie_id= ts.tag_serie_id and tag_season_num = ts.tag_season_num)

FROM taggedshows as ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a bit nested but i think you need two level subquery

```
select * from taggedshows
where (tag_season_num, tag_episode_num)  in 
    (select tag_season_num, max(tag_episode_num)  from  taggedshows
    where ( tag_series_id , tag_season_num) in 
    (select tag_series_id max(tag_season_num)  from taggedshows
    group by tag_seried_id)
    group by tag_season_num)
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer but query doesn''t work.  I suppose you've wanted to put in where clause tag_season_num `select * from taggedshows
where (taggedshows, tag_episode_num)` . Anyways I've fixed it and query still doesnt work

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I think this is it :)